# Is there a Cambodian community area in Bangkok?

Tags: bangkok

In Bangkok, I found by chance a Burmese market at Phra Khanong area and a Vietnamese market at Samsen area. There is also a China town in the city.

But is there an area with many immigrants from Cambodia where one can find traditional Cambodian foods?